# Sharing a password for short term access to a shared resource

Tags: password-management, secret-sharing

I sometimes need to delegate access to a single-user/shared user website for short term administration purposes (eg. with a junior administrator for programmed maintenance).

I have requested multiple accounts, but apparently it is not an option.

My solution would be to change the password to a shared value *before* access, and change it back to the default password *after*.

I would record both passwords in the company password manager.

Do you see problems with this approach, and do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Is a password the only possible authentication method?

Comment: good comment, got me thinking... you are probably right, there are other ways of accessing the services. I believe this service provides alternative control panels (at a price) and an API if I had time to develop.

Comment: You are welcome. Since you provided only limited information about the system it is hard to recomment something, but at least I could help you a bit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is right; while you want to keep just one account and share it with others for a while, the best way is to change password before-share and then re-change after-share.